# Are all divisors in a very ample linear system on a smooth variety smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $\mathcal{L}$ a very ample line bundle. It seems to me that in this situation any $D\in |\mathcal{L}|$ is smooth, since it is (isomorphic to) the intersection of a smooth variety with a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$, and hence smooth. Is this correct?

Comment: Intersections of smooth varieties have no reasons to be smooth !

Comment: @N.H. Of course, something I shouldn't have overlooked... If you add this as an answer I'll accept it, since it adreses the flaw in my reasoning more directly then the other answer.

Comment: No problems ! You can accept the other answer :) Notice that the key word is transversality : if $X,Y$ are smooth and intersect transversally then $X \cap Y$ is smooth.

Comment: Thanks @N.H. - I must say I also think you did a great job of explaining this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, take $X = \mathbb P^N$ and take $\mathcal L = \mathcal O(d)$ (with $d > 1$). The divisors in your linear system are degree $d$ hypersurfaces. And it is very easy to think of singular hypersurfaces!

However, a *generic* divisor in your very ample linear system is smooth. This follows from Bertini's theorem.